# get_the_post_thumbnail_url gives weird results

Tags: wordpress

This is for an RSS feed

EDIT: This was a question originally about get_the_post_thumbnail_url, but ultimately the output of this function was being overwritten by a filter.

However amarinediary did provide a correct answer, below.

Also, if anyone has difficulties with gmail not showing images in an email, know that prepending the img src with https: solved the problem for me.

Thanks, Richard

Comment: Hi Richard, WordPress returns this kind of url on purpose, so it can work both in http and https. Why exactly do you need to have the https?

Comment: Good question. I have a newsletter with ActiveCampaign that reads my RSS file. Long story short, without https: in the RSS, gmail will not show the images. Who knows why. Took a long time to figure that out, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### Loop

```
<?php
if( have_posts() ):
    while( have_posts() ): the_post();
        if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
          esc_url( the_post_thumbnail_url() );
        endif;
    endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

---

### Output

```
https://domain.../file.png
```

Tested and working.

---

### Learn more

- `has_post_thumbnail` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/
- `the_post_thumbnail_url` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail_url/

Comment: ```esc_url( the_post_thumbnail_url() )``` returns nothing but if I add get

```esc_url( get_the_post_thumbnail_url() )``` returns ```//domain.../file.png```

Comment: `the_post_thumbnail_url`, **DISPLAY** the post thumbnail URL. @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail_url/. You might be messing something up on your end. This is literally the goal of this function.